# runtime error 1004 appears in copy of file but not original

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have an advanced filter which pulls data out of a separate workbook (opened earlier on) using defined ranges (which are visible in name manager across all sheets). After i have the data I then want to be able to save a copy of the workbook for reference.

```
Range("stresslist").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("stressfind"), CopyToRange:=Range("stressout"), Unique:=True
```

This worked fine before Christmas but now all of the copies give "runtime error 1004 method 'range' of object '_global' failed" which i've narrowed down to

```
Range("stresslist")
```

which is the range on another workbook consisting of 3 columns.

does anyone know why it's only failing in the copy, or a way I can make it work in both the copy and the original?

Thanks

Matt

Entire code

```
Sub findstress()

datafile = "Datafile.xlsx"
calcfile = ThisWorkbook.Name
dataopen = False
frontend = ActiveSheet.Name
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Open Data workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks(datafile).Activate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Application.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & datafile

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Application.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\" & datafile
        End If

    Else
        dataopen = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


Workbooks(calcfile).Activate

Range("stresslist").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("stressfind"), CopyToRange:=Range("stressout"), Unique:=True



'close data file if not open before
    If Not dataopen Then
    Workbooks(datafile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Method that works for anyone else with the same problem, but takes a little while to run (probably due to the amount of the data) so still looking for a better solution if anybody has one.

```
datafile = "Datafile.xlsx"
calcfile = ThisWorkbook.Name
dataopen = False
frontend = ActiveSheet.Name

'Copy relevant data
    Workbooks(datafile).Activate
    stresslist = Sheets("Data").Range("stresslist")

'Create new sheet "Temp" and insert Data
    Workbooks(calcfile).Activate
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "Temp"
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A:C") = stresslist

Worksheets(frontend).Activate

Workbooks(calcfile).Sheets("Temp").Range("A:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("stressfind"), CopyToRange:=Range("stressout"), Unique:=True

'Delete Sheet "Temp"
Sheets("Temp").Delete
```

works by activating the workbook with the data in then copying it into variable, then activating the original workbook and dumping the data into a new "Temp" sheet. Then deleting the "Temp" sheet afterwards.

This works fine but is a lot slower than before, and as the same thing is also being used with more data in another macro that already takes a while to run, I'm still looking for a better way.

Thanks for any better suggestions
Matt

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is, you need to ensure the Name Range still exists in the workbook or not.

Secondly, as a Best Practice, you should always use the Parent Sheet Name where the Name Range Exists. For example, if my name exists in a sheet called Data, so you should do something like this:

```
Range("stresslist").AdvancedFilter....
```

You should use like this:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Dim rng as Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Data")
Set rng = sht.Range("StressList")

rng.AdvanceFilter .....
```

When you use Global functions like Range, Cells etc, what it tries to do is to try find a range with the name in the active sheet, or the name range stored globally. Avoiding using the hierarchy while making an Object can lead to errors for many reasons which vary from situation to situation. If you would like to know more about your error, please supply with your whole code, and we can then try to find the exact problem.

Thanks,
Vikas B

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is the range is in a separate workbook not just another sheet. I've uploaded the whole code (may be one or two mistakes as i accidentally saved over my backup with the one i was editing). I've managed to get it working by creating a new sheet in the same workbook and dumping the data into it (which I'll upload once I'm allowed to answer the question), but it takes a while and i have somewhere else that uses this code which already takes a little while. Thanks Matt

Comment: I have a temporary solution which should work for smaller data sets, but copying the entire database from one workbook to another just to delete it again takes quite a while when it was fairly instant before. As I need to use it repeatedly (possibly a few hundred times) I would prefer a way to read from the other workbook directly. Thanks